# Would it Be Possible to Install Windows XP on This Machine

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, drivers

Would it be possible to uninstall Windows 7 & then install Windows XP (64 bit) on this machine:

http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/model/DT.SJPAA.002

I purchased that machine, but Windows 7 is causing severe compatibility issues with the software that I use to run basically my entire business.

Is it possible to uninstall Windows 7, and then install Windows XP (64 bit) while still having all the features of that computer work (SATA 3.0, usb 3.0 ports, etc, etc)?

Comment: Have you thought of virtual guests? You can run either Virtual Box or VM Player with Win XP in them.

Comment: Have you considered running XP Mode, which is a virtual XP environment inside Windows 7?

Comment: I'm afraid not, no.  I run an appraisal company, and the machine that I purchased (the one referenced in my question) acts as a server for four other Windows XP machines to run off of.  The new machine purchased replaced a much older PC that was running Windows XP.  Since replacing that machine with this new machine running Windows 7, I'm having severe problems.  I called the platinum tech support number for the software I run, and they told me I need to have & run windows XP.

Comment: XP 64 is notoriously bad with driver support. I doubt you would be able to get everything working again even if there are xp drivers listed.

Comment: Technically speaking, the software I run my appraisal business with is compatible with Windows 7, but the platinum tech support I pay for told me that I am probably going to run into many many issues by having a "mixed network" of machines (XP workstations with Windows 7 as a server) and that my best solution is to have the server run the same OS as the workstations, so I'm pretty sure that "XP mode" won't actually solve anything.

Comment: XP Mode, maybe not, but a virtualised XP running on VirtualBox or VMWare is a different story.

Comment: @Kyle - You say "even if there are XP drivers listed" <- Where are you referring to?  I mean, if I do want to give this a go, where do I look for the correct drivers?

Comment: Generally from the vendor of the device that you need a driver for.

Comment: At the end of the day the only real answer we can give is "try it and see".

Comment: @robert I mean on the Acer Support Website, I just followed the link you provided. I can't seem to browse the products though, search isn't working either.

Comment: @robert Actually the site works fine on IE 9/win7, I guess it just doesn't like FF14.1/ubuntu 12.04. However, they don't have xp drivers listed: http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/drivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it's possible.
you will how ever have to format the machine and then need a valid windows XP installation CD to have windows XP installed.

From what I understand the windows 7 also provides a compatibility mode; where you can run windows XP programs. have you taken a look at that?

Comment: Yes, I have a valid Windows XP (64 bit) license to install on the machine.  My concern is drivers.  I'm savvy enough to (think)/know that just formatting the drive & installing XP won't be enough, and that many things just won't function...ports, drives, etc, etc.

Comment: once you have successfully installed XP; most of the drivers can be explored by XP itself; if not I am sure you might have the drivers as well. Since windows 7 also provides a compatibility mode have you tried the approach?

Comment: try to look at this: http://lifehacker.com/5245396/set-up-and-use-xp-mode-in-windows-7

Comment: +1 for XP mode. That sounds like the best solution here. Or Virtual Box.